# LINK URL IN NetSuite Hosted tab

Tags: netsuite

I have a website hosted in NetSuite. 
I can see that there is hosted tab in the website. LINK URL is mentioned for that tab. how can i get the content of the tab? I mean how can I identify the HTML it is fetching for the content. there is no entry in the Website Page. 
I need to modify the content of the tab. but not finding the HTML for this tab.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

Open below path

`lists > web site > Content Manager`

click on site map
select ur tab and edit. 
add ur text on message box.

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [doc](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteCommerceWebSite/SuiteCommerceSiteBuilder/HostedTabs.html).

> To create a hosted tab: 1. Go to Lists > Web Site > Tabs.  ...

You should view and edit your hosted tab under Lists > Web Site > Tabs.